# How to find meta from the main site?

Tags: support, per-site-meta

Say I want to find meta stackexchange. Is there any conspicuous link from main site to it's meta?

Is there such feature already?

I usually found that on google.

Comment: The answers there provide a lot of alternatives to find a child meta from a main site.

Comment: Say I am on psychology stackexchange. Say I want to go to meta psychology stackexchange. Are there links from psychology stackexchange to meta psychology stackexchange.

Comment: Yes, a couple of them. There's probably a proper duplicate for this question but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Another related/duplicate question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302510/295232