# Could you put a link on Medical Sciences Stack Exchange so finding the Meta is easier?

Tags: feature-request

On Stack Exchange, it is easy to get to meta via the links to posts there.
The space where those links are is used for other content on medicalsciences.stackexchange.
I knew the address meta.stackexchange.com, so I tried meta.medicalsciences.stackexchange.com. I got a security alert because the certificate does not cover that address.
So I posted to meta.stackexchange. Someone migrated it rapidly, which I liked a lot, thanks. If anyone gets here looking for it, here's the address - https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hey ToMath! There's a link at the footer of the page named Feedback. It will help one to go to the per-site meta. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wddeo.png

Comment: Thanks, Random Person. I asked for a link and there already is one.
Some (weak?) caveats:
It can be a long way to get to the footer.
If you are looking for the word "Meta", you may not realise that "Feedback" means the same thing unless you happen to do a mouseover.

Comment: ToMath, please read these posts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372787 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367982

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find meta from the main site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315401/how-to-find-meta-from-the-main-site)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty easy already:

From the Hamburger menu:
[image]

Or from the Help menu:
[image]

Or in the footer:
[image]

Comment: Well - I'm of the opinion that it would be really nice to add both Meta and Chat to the left sidebar