# How to find the meta place of each site with a screen reader

Tags: feature-request, status-review, per-site-meta, accessibility

I do know the basic question of [where to find the Meta of each site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302510/how-do-users-navigate-to-meta) has already been asked and answered, but I am still having difficulty finding it. I use a screen reader, and, until I read the answer to that linked question, I was unable to find it.

This is a screenshot of what I came to:
[image: Example of a "tour" page on a Stack Exchange site]

I was able to get to the tour page through the links at the bottom.

With the screen reader built-in on my PC (Macbook Pro with/ VoiceOver), it was able to open the first menu on the left part of the navbar, listing things such as Questions, Tags, Users [(here is an example)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour), but unable to open the ones on the right, so when I heard "Help center and other resources" I still only thought it would contain one help page. I also think it makes sense to place links to help in the easiest place to find, such as under that same left-side menu. Would it be considered so it can be added (not moved) to the first menu as well, since it would be the easiest to access for some of us, as well as it fitting with what many people probably click to ask questions, so we can be reminded we have access to the help page prior to asking questions? Considering how Meta of each site is also a similar QNA page, it would make sense for that to also be considered as a place to ask the questions.

Comment: It would help if you state the width of your screen/window, which screen reader you're using, and the actions which you took to open the menu where you're asking for links to be placed. Having that information should allow SE developers to duplicate what you're experiencing. Unfortunately, "the first menu on the left part of the navbar" isn't enough of a description to know for certain which area of the page you mean, because what that could refer to changes based on both screen/window width and options which can be set by the user. [Note: that you mean the topbar is also an assumption.]

Comment: How hard is it for you to edit the URL in the address bar? As a non-user of screen readers, it’s my preferred method (just press Ctrl-L and type in `meta.` in the appropriate place), but I’m not sure if it makes sense to recommend.

Comment: @Makyen I have edited it to include the device and screen reader I am using, as well as a link to an example page.

Comment: @user3840170 It is not difficult, but my question is definitely about finding it the first time or forgetting it is just `/meta`. Meta is mentioned on the help pages without an explanation of how we can access it (including the URL).

Comment: I've been, well nagging to [bring links to meta and chat to the sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383093/could-we-bring-chat-and-meta-to-the-sidebar). I guess this is another reason to do this.

Comment: Go to your profile, on right side there is "Profiles button" besides the Edit Profile. Click on it and click on Meta User. While in Meta of that site again use this method to go back to that main site. (PS: Don't use this method in Meta StackExchange, you know obviously why). It would be easier to go to meta this way, just a few more clicks

Comment: @JitendraSingh no it's not easier and you missed the part about screen reader.

Comment: It looks like your screenreader skipped the `header` tag.  It has a `nav` element in it with the "menubar". There is a difference between that `nav` element and the `nav` element your reader has found. The latter has an ARIA attribute `role="navigation"`. The nav element in the header is missing any ARIA hints. That looks like an omission because the  child elements have proper and by the looks of it correct ARIA attributes. So my hope is an SE dev can make this minor change and see if that helps the screenreader to pick up the top-bar as well.